# using sed to replace a key/value in a yaml file

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed

I have a yaml file that I need to update using a sed command in a script.
Here is the file:

```
> server_options:
>     key1: value1
>     key2: value2
>     key3: value3
>     key4: value4
>     
> 
> client_options:
>     key5: value5
>     key6: value6
>     key2: value8
>     key3: value3
>     # key4: value4
>     # key7: value7
```

The output should be:

```
> server_options:
>     key1: value1
>     key2: xxx
>     key3: value3
>     key4: yyy
>     
> 
> client_options:
>     key5: value5
>     key6: value6
>     key2: value8
>     key3: value3
>     # key4: value4
>     # key7: value7
```

The keys are pre-fixed by a tab and I just wan't to update the value for the first occurrence of key2 and key4. Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: add the code you tried to solve this...

Comment: Why the value `# key7: value7` changed to `# key4: value4` in the client_options?

Comment: Every line starts with `>` and one white space?

Comment: The lines containing server_options and client_options starts with no white space where as other lines start with a tab.

Comment: @CWLiu - sorry, it was a typo. client_options doesn't change at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
sed -i '0,/^\([[:space:]]*key2: *\).*/s//\1xxx/;0,/\([[:space:]]*key4: *\).*/s//\1yyy/;' file
```

- the `0` address is to match the first occurrence of following pattern
- `/^\([[:space:]]key2: \).*/`: search and capture zero or more space or tab followed by `key2:`
- `s//`: subsitute matching string
- ...with captured key and the new value

And the same for the second substitution.

The `-i` flag is to edit the file *in place*.

Comment: sed '0,/^\([[:space:]]key2: \).*/s//\1xxx/;0,/\([[:space:]]key4: \).*/s//\1yyy/;' test.yaml

`server_options:
        key1: value1
        key2: value2
        key3: value3
        key4: yyy


client_options:
        key5: value5
        key6: value6
        key2: value8
        key3: value3
        # key4: value4
        # key7: value7`

not sure why key2 is not updating.

Comment: Maybe extra tabs or space before or after the key. I edited, tell me if it works.